# Slim framework app->render

Tags: php, jquery, slim

I have two routes,get method where visualize all data, and post method where insert the data.In the get method using the app-render ('view name', and the data), and so good.In the method post I will do the same in order to see the end inserting the same page with a popup that contains a success message. The two methods have the same url, the problem is that when I render in the post method, I view the page with half of the contents because it does not recognize the data in hand with the get method.

```
$app->get('/url.html',function()use($app){
     //code
     $app->render('url.html', array('name'=>$variable1,'user'=>$variable2)));   

});
```

**I want to display the pop-up after insert**

```
$app->post('/url.html',function()use($app){

     //code

     $popup='$(function(){$( "#dialog-message" ).dialog({modal: true, buttons: {Ok: function() {$( this ).dialog( "close" );}}});});';
     $app->render('url.html', array('popup'=>$popup)                                                )); 

});
```

**In the view "/url.html"**

```
<?php echo $popup ?>
```

But does not work

then summing up the view does not work in the post method and the popup

Comment: Is there any error in javascript console? Based on your view, I think it's missing jQuery, right?